# how to pass via node js (express server) different html pages with different parameters

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

js server that receives id as a query parameter.
I want each time a client connects with different parameters to pass him a different html page each page has a simple UI with 2 dynamic arrays everything works fine but the image isn't showing, when I open the html itself alone it works fine would love to get some help.

This is my server code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
  
// Helper function to read and serve html files 
// according to the requested paths 
function readAndServe(path, res) {
    fs.readFile(path, function (err, data) {
        res.end(data);
    })
}
  
// Setting get request path to receive id as query parameter 
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params);
  
    // Mapping different id's with respective html files
    if (req.params.id == "screen=1")
        readAndServe("./1.html", res);
    else if (req.params.id == "screen=2")
        readAndServe("./2.html", res);
    else if (req.params.id == "screen=3")
        readAndServe("./3.html", res);
    else {
        res.end("Invalid request");
    }
});
  
app.listen(8080, () => { console.log("Server Listening on Port 8080") });
```

this is one of my html's they are all the same logic just diffrent text and images

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href=
"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <style>
         img{
         height: 500px;
         width: 450px;
         }
         h1{
         color: darkgreen;
         margin-top: 20px;
         font-family: Comic Sans MS, cursive, sans-serif;
         }
         .button{
         margin-left: 45%;
         }
      </style>
      <script>

         function changeImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById("img");
    img.src = images[x];
    x++;        
    if(x >= images.length) {
        x = 0;
    } 
   setTimeout("changeImage()", 6000);
   }

         function changeText() {
   var txt= document.getElementById("message");
   txt.textContent = text[y];
   y++;
   if(y>= text.length){
      y = 0;
   }
   setTimeout("changeText()", 6000);

   }


var text = [], y=0;
text[0] = "Message1";
text[3] = "Message2";
text[1] = "Message3";
text[2] = "Message4";
setTimeout("changeText()", 6000);
var images = [], x = 0;
images[0] = "image0.jpg"
images[3] = "image1.jpg";
images[1] = "image2.jpg";
images[2] = "image3.jpg";
setTimeout("changeImage()", 6000);

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
               <h1 id="message">
                  Message2

               </h1>
               <img  id="img"
                     src="image1.jpg"  >
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are the images in a public folder ? You must make it public to serve static content

Comment: they are in a folder on the desktop in the same folder from where the server is running when i run the html itself everything works fine but when i request it through the parameter only the text is changing and the image isnt showing

Comment: All your "mapping different ids" code could simply be written `app.get('/:id', (req, res) => readAndServe(\`./${req.params.id}.html\`, res));`. This avoid writing things like `if(id==1) then 1, else if(id==2) then 2, else if(id==3) then 3, else if(id==4) then 4, else if(id==5) then 5` all the way to 89871671451423

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `express.static` middleware to use static files like images, css files etc.

1.Create a folder for static files. For instance 'public'.

2.Just put this line after you define the `app` variable

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

3.Put all your static files in that folder.

Remember, after defining static folder, you shouldn't write the folder name in your paths. For instance, not `public/image1.jpg`, But just `image1.jpg` .

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Hey i moved all the images to a public folder added the exact line underneath where i defined my app variable and changed the source of the image in the html folder and still no luck =[

Comment: First don't forget to restart your node server. Second, you shouldn't write the public folder name in the path. Just src="image1.jpg" is enough. Have you done it this way?

Comment: Don't change the images URL. You don't say what exactly you did, but I assume you changed `"image0.jpg"` to `"public/image0.jpg"`. Don't do that (for that matter, the answer never told you to). Just keep `"image0.jpg"`, and Express will look for it in its public folder. If you use `"public/image0.jpg"`, Express will tell you the route `.get('/public/:imageName')` is not defined, which is right.